# SQLite Column not created

Tags: android, sql, database, sqlite

Ok so I have no idea what the problem is. I get an error saying that the sender_id column does not exist. I have two tables, the user table is created just fine and all the column names are constants.

```
  public String CREATE_USER_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TableData.TableInfo.USER_TABLE +
        " ( "+ TableData.TableInfo.USER_NAME +" TEXT PRIMARY KEY, "
             + TableData.TableInfo.USER_PASS +" TEXT, "
             + TableData.TableInfo.USER_FNAME + " TEXT, "
             + TableData.TableInfo.USER_LNAME + " TEXT);";
//Create Message table
public String CREATE_MSG_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TableData.TableInfo.MSG_TABLE +
        " ( " + TableData.TableInfo.MESSAGE_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, "
        + TableData.TableInfo.RECEIVER_ID + " TEXT, "
        + TableData.TableInfo.SENDER_ID + " TEXT, "
        + TableData.TableInfo.MESSAGE + " TEXT, "
        + TableData.TableInfo.STATUS + " INTEGER);";
```

The User table is created just fine and I have no issues accessing information. But I get errors trying to access the message table.

```
 public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sdb){
    sdb.execSQL(CREATE_USER_TABLE);
    Log.d("Database operations", "Table1 created");
    sdb.execSQL(CREATE_MSG_TABLE);
    Log.d("Database operations", "Table2 created");

}
```

And this is where I query the table to add a row.

```
  public void putInformationMsgTable(DatabaseOperations dop,String senderID,String receiverID, String text, int status)
{
    SQLiteDatabase SQ = dop.getWritableDatabase();

    SQ.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + TableData.TableInfo.MSG_TABLE +
            " (" + TableData.TableInfo.MESSAGE_ID +
            ", " + TableData.TableInfo.RECEIVER_ID +
            ", " + TableData.TableInfo.SENDER_ID +
            ", " + TableData.TableInfo.MESSAGE +
            ", " + TableData.TableInfo.STATUS + ")" +
            " VALUES (" + null + ", "
            + receiverID + ", "
            + senderID + ", "
            + text + ", "
            + status + ")");

    Log.d("Database operations", "One row inserted into message table");
}
```

I know there are a lot of threads out there on this topic but both my professor and I are stumped. My syntax seems correct and there is no reason that this shouldn't work. Any thoughts?!

EDIT: These are the constants I am working with 
**I also changed the value of the constant MESSAGE_ID to msg_id and the error now says "table msg_info has no column named msg_id (code 1)"

```
        //User Table
    public static final String USER_NAME = "user_name";
    public static final String USER_PASS = "user_pass";
    public static final String USER_FNAME = "user_fname";
    public static final String USER_LNAME = "user_lname";
    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "user_info";
    public static final String USER_TABLE = "user_info";

    //Message Table
    public static final String MESSAGE_ID = "rowid";
    public static final String RECEIVER_ID = "receiver_id";
    public static final String SENDER_ID = "sender_id";
    public static final String MESSAGE = "message";
    public static final String STATUS = "status";
    public static final String MSG_TABLE = "msg_info";
```

Comment: Your first step should be to figure out what the strings `CREATE_USER_TABLE`, `CREATE_MSG_TABLE` and the one you're trying to use to insert actually are. You should include those here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**rowid cannot be valid column name**.

It's like using **if** variable in programming. We cannot use that because it's a reserved keyword.
The word is already reserved.

See [here](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html#rowid)

**Solution** would be to use something like **row_id** for MESSAGE_ID

Comment: I changed the name of the column to msg_id and now the error message is "table msg_info has no column named msg_id (code 1)"

Comment: did you change the database version/ uninstall the app?

Comment: I just did that, I do not get an error about the table now I get an error about my INSERT query stating that there is no such column named 'jsmith' which is the receiverID variable I passed into the function

Comment: That would be a different question. Sorry the forum isn't supposed to discuss multiple scenario at a same question. Please make another question about it and ask again. Thank you

Comment: No problem, you answered the question on this forum so thanks!